# How many LED lights on this 15 amp breaker?

Tags: electrical

How many LED recessed lights per 15 amp breaker with 14 gauge 12/3 12/2 wire with 8 3 way dimmer switches and 1 single pole dimmer attached picture of 6” recessed led lights

[image]

Also not sure what the maximum of (4)  no 12 awg or (6)  No 14 awg means... thanks guys

Comment: "Maximum of..." is referring to the max conductor fill for that light's junction box.

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/40147/how-many-lighting-circuits-are-needed-in-the-led-era-us-nec

Answer (score 3):

The breaker only sees the 120V input to the LED power supply, so 
at 0.14A each 100 of them would still be less than 15A.

However you're surposed to use less tha 80% of breaker capacity, so 85 is a better limit.

Answer (score 2):

### Amp ratings: derate, add, and compare

The 0.14A rating (or VA divided by your line voltage) indicates the maximum amps it might draw.

Since the device is a light, you must increase this number by 125%, so you are now at 0.175A.

You must make similar calculations on all other hardwired loads on the circuit, increasing by 125% if they are *continuous loads* or certain statutory items which must be treated as continuous loads.

Add them all together, they cannot exceed the breaker rating.  (15A)

If the hardwired loads add up to more than 50% of breaker rating, there cannot be *any* receptacles on the circuit.

### Box fill

Based on the stated cubic inches (9.2), the box can hold four #12 or  #14 wires.

The labeling is saying they got an exception from UL allowing six #14 wires, since five is pretty useless.